# Show that $3^{2008} + 4^{2009}$ can be written as product of two positive integers, each of which is larger than $2009^{182}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, contest-math, factoring

> Show that $3^{2008} + 4^{2009}$ can be written as product of two positive integers, each of which is larger than $2009^{182}$.

To show that $3^{2008} + 4^{2009}$ is composite, I used the Sophie-Germain identity:
$$[a^4 + 4b^4 = (a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2)(a^2 − 2ab + 2b^2)]$$

So, I got:
$$(3^{502})^4 + 4(4^{502})^4$$
Which gives:
$$(3^{1004}+2(3^{502} \cdot 4^{502}) + 2\cdot 4^{1004})\cdot(3^{1004}-2(3^{502} \cdot 4^{502}) + 2\cdot4^{1004})$$

I don't know how to simplify this further and compare it with $2009^{182}$ and check whether my method is correct or not. If the factorization is such that both the factors are greater than $2009^{182}$, then how to prove it? If the factors are not greater than $2009^{182}$, then we're back to square $1$. How to proceed further?

Comment: $252 \times 4 = 1008$.  You must mean $502$, not $252$.

Comment: Once you do that, you may observe that $2 \times 4^{1004} = 2^{2009} > 2^{2002} = 2^{11 \times 182} = 2048^{182} > 2009^{182}$.  You'll have to do a comparison with the subtracted middle term in your second factor, of course.

Comment: Observe also $3^{502} \times 4^{502} = 12^{502} < 12^{504} = 12^{3 \times 168} = 1728^{168} < 2009^{168}$.  That should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{2008}{4}=502$, not $252$. In any case, it suffices to show that
$$3^{1004} - 2\times3^{502}\times4^{502}+2\times4^{1004}>2009^{182}$$
Note that $2\times3^{502}\times4^{502}< 4^{1004}$, so we just need to show that $4^{1004}>2009^{182}$ (In comparison $3^{1004}$ is quite insignificant). We have $2009< 2^{11} = 2048$, so $2009^{182} < 2^{182\times 11} = 4^{1001} < 4^{1004}$ and we are done.